# Matrix/vector sizes in proof of Denton, Parke, Tao, Zhan eigenvector/eigenvalue result

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I do not understand a really basic part of Lemma 1 in this [arxiv paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1908.03795.pdf). For completeness, the lemma is:

> Let one eigenvalue of $A$ be zero, WLOG we can set $\lambda_n(A) = 0$. Then,
>
> $$\prod_{i=1}^{n-1} \lambda_i(A) |\det(B v_n)^2| = \det(B^* A B) $$
>
> for any $n \times n - 1$ matrix $B$.

Above, $A$ is an $n \times n$ Hermitian matrix with $\lambda_i(A)$ eigenvalues and $v_i$ eigenvectors. My question is: if $B$ is a $n \times n - 1$ matrix and $v_n$ is an $n$-vector, how is $B v_n$ a valid matrix-vector multiplication?

In the paper, there's a weird space between $B$ and $v_n$, and I'm not sure if I'm missing something obvious.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I emailed the first author, and he said that "$B\;\;\ v_n$" is not a matrix-vector multiplication, but an $n \times n$ matrix or

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
B & v_n
\end{bmatrix}
$$

This explains the weird spacing.

Comment: While at that, $n \times n-1$ should be $n \times \left(n-1\right)$ as well.